# Array will only echo last output when saving to a variable PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the following function in my php program.

```
$out = "";

printArray($_POST);
function printArray($array){
    global $out;
     foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        $out = "$key: $value <br>";
    } 
}

echo $out;
```

Its supposed to get all my post values along with there variable names and save it all to a variable but it only echos out the last one in my list. Meanwhile if i dont save the output of the foreach to a variable...

```
printArray($_POST);

function printArray($array){
     foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        echo "$key: $value <br>";
    } 
}
```

it outputs just fine.

```
first_name: Test
last_name: Test
dob1:
dob2:
dob3:
current_grade:
shcool:
M_C:
type_of_session_text:
date_session_info:
(shortened for brevity)
```

whats going on here?

Comment: You're overwriting the variable in each loop. Decide if you want to concatenate it to a string or add it to an array.

Comment: You should not get in the habit of using global either. You could do this easily with a `return`. Something like `$out = printArray($_POST);` and in your function `return $whatever_you_set;`

Comment: so like ```function printArray($array){
    $out = "";
     foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        $out.= "$key: $value <br>";
        return $out;
    } 
}

echo $out;``` ??

Comment: op whoops that got kind of screwed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because every itteration you set `$out` again without keeping the previous values. You could do:

```
function printArray($array){
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        $out .= $key.": ".$value."<br>";
    } 
    return $out;
}
```

With the `.=` you "add" more string to that variable. The technical term is 'concatenate'.

Also, `global` should be avoided as it is a mayor red flag of bad programming. A function should return a value, the logic that calls the function decides what to do with it. I recommend you do a little research into 'pure' functions (easy concept).

Comment: While your answer was correct, it lacked a *why*, "Why does this answer work", "what did it fix that the question had wrong" :) So i've added it to your answer